# How to re-migrate already Migrated dbcontext in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, migration

I have a project call RemoteWork where i have my Dbcontext. I have 2 models inside the DbContext - USER and PRODUCTS. I was using code first approach. I then used the "add-migration" and it was successful. I then referenced the Remotework in another project call Apiclient. They are both in the same solution. Now I have altered my table in USER and so it was out of sync. I wanted to make it to be in sync. I have tried different methods i have read online, I was getting different error messages. Can anyone please help in this regard.

I have done this:  Add-Migration SecondMigration

This is the error message:

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'AppClient'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

Please note that AppClient was made as the startup project. I have also tried making remotework as a start up project, it did not resolve it either:

> `PM> Add-Migration SecondMigration`

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'AppClient'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

> `PM> Add-Migration -Name MyMigration -OutputDir MyMigrationDir -Context BettingDbContext -Project RemoteWork -StartupProject AppClient`

I wanted the models to be in sync with my database

Comment: Please, check the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running `add-migration` from the package manager console in visual studio.
Either make sure you have selected the project that contains your context in the "Default project" dropdown at the top of the package manager console. Or use the `-StartUpProjectName` argument on add-migration.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes I was using the package manager console. I have picked the project containing the dbcontext which is - REMOTEWORK but I still got an error. The error is: PM> Add-Migration SecondMigration .
ERROR: Could not load assembly 'AppClient'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'RemoteWork'.

Comment: Try also setting your startup project to the one containing dbcontext.

Comment: Thanks again. I did that but it still gave the same error.

Comment: @OfficalMesut Thanks for your message. Please i have checked the website but  I did not know where to put step 4 (i.e. configure the migration assembly). Do I also need to copy from appsetting.json and replace the "connectionstring"  that is stated in step 4. I will be glad for any help you render at this point to resolve this.